# Acessar os arquivos de fora da public_html

Tags: composer, organização-de-projeto

É possível acessar de maneira coerente arquivos fora da pasta public_html no servidor para renderizar uma View?

O que preciso é chamar arquivos `js` e css e apontar as imagens que estão dentro da camada *View* que está em app. Esta por sua vez estaria no mesmo nível da `public_html`, e não dentro dela. A `public_html` conteria apenas uma arquivo chamado `index.php` e o `.htaccess`. A `index.php` chamaria o `Init.php` na raiz de app que define as rotas e passa para o Core da aplicação renderizar o layout através do arquivo `Bootstrap.php`

O MVC

```
app/
    Model/
    View/
        templates/
            css/
            img/
            js/
    Controller/
vendor/
    composer/
    Core/
pubic_html/
    - index.php
```

Comment: Ué, não é só usar o caminho absoluto, e dar as devidas permissões. Você também pode chegar ao arquivo utilizando ".." para acessar o diretório "acima". Seria bom informar qual framework esta utilizando

Comment: É meu próprio framework com base no zend. Já tentei acessar os caminhos com '..', com o caminho absoluto, mas não adianta. Só funciona quando eu coloco os arquivos dentro da public_html, o que não é viável porque desestrutura meu MVC. Eu sei que é possível porque já vi em outros sites eles acessando arquivos css e js de forma que não era possível clicar no link para visualizar o conteúdo. Quero muito encontrar essa solução para poder disponibilizar no meu blog e postar nas comunidades porque sei que é uma dúvida muito comum e pelas minhas pesquisas, nunca solucionada abertamente.

Answer (score 1):

Arquivos estáticos devem estar na pasta pública ou “document root”.

De outra maneira, ou seja, da forma como quer manter a estrutura de arquivos e diretórios, teria que fazer um [stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851849/output-an-image-in-php) ou um esquema com [proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21537306/use-php-to-proxy-images) para que os arquivos estáticos (css, js, imagens) sejam acessíveis publicamente.

Normalmente isso é desnecessário e custa muito processamento e memória. A grosso modo, não faz sentido.

Para resolver, tudo que for **público**, coloque na pasta **pública**.

Se possui um motivo específico para que as imagens estejam fora da pasta pública, então a conversa é diferente. Estaríamos falando de [xsend_file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80186/using-x-sendfile-with-apache-php) e coisas do tipo.

Quanto ao CSS e JS, podem até ficar fora e ser compilado com algum esquema de template engine, inclusive muitas plataformas adotam tal prática, mas isso é um nível mais complexo e acredito que o seu sistema não está nesse nível de desenvolvimento devido a natureza da pergunta.

Vale salientar que isso tudo nada tem a ver com MVC:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Por que você não faz o inverso (e mais correto)?

Você pode criar uma estrutura básica dentro do seu public_html. Algo assim:

```
/public_html
    /src
    /web
    .htaccess
```

Dentro do seu .htacess você coloca para ler a pasta /web como se fosse a raiz:
[Aqui você encontra um exemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10427485/6642228)